# Java lost exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, finally

Suppose we have following method (a very simplified version):

```
    void doSomething() {
      try {
        throw new Exception("A");
      } finally {
        throw new Exception("B");
      }
    }
```

Exception with message "B" is caught in the caller method. Basically, is there any way of knowing which exception was thrown in try block if finally block also throws some exception? Suppose method doSomething() cannot be modified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Section 14.20.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) states:

> If execution of the try block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value V, ...

...

> If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and the throw of value V is discarded and forgotten).

Java must discard the original exception `V` ("complete abruptly") and the whole try-finally block "completes abruptly" with `S` (the `finally` `Exception`, "B").

There is no way to retrieve the original `try` block exception "A", which corresponds to `V` in the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

finally block will consume any return values or exceptions from the try-catch blocks.

Basically, finally clauses are there to ensure proper release of a resource. However, if an exception is thrown inside the finally block, it consume any return values or exceptions from the try-catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually, but it's a bit of a PITA.

```
public class ExceptionException
{

   public static void main( String[] args )
           throws Exception
   {
      Exception saved = null;
      try {
         throw new Exception( "A" );
      } catch( Exception ex ) {
         saved = ex;
      } finally {
         try {
            throw new Exception( "B" );
         } catch( Exception ex ) {
            if( saved != null )
               ex.addSuppressed( saved );
         }
      }
   }
}
```

As rgettman stated, the JLS says that exceptions thrown from a finally clause normally cause other exceptions to be forgotten.  Moral: try really hard to not throw exceptions from a finally clause.